# How can I permanently rename a window (in XFCE)?

Tags: xorg, window-manager, xfce, xdotools

I tend to have a bunch of windows of the same applications (terminals and text editors) and they can be a problem to manage. It would help me a lot if I could give them the most intuitive and clear names.

I found how to do it working directly with X, but most applications rename their windows very often and this doesn't last:

```
xdotool selectwindow set_window --name "ORG"
```

Is there any way to make it permament?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DevilsPie](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/DevilsPie) for this. There is no nativ way to do this in Xfwm4.